# Not able to click on Login button using selenium webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Hi I am trying to automate https://www.nextgenerationautomation.com and unable to click on login / SignUp button using Selenium 4

Steps:

1. Navigate to URL: https://www.nextgenerationautomation.com
2. Click on LogIn/SignUp button.

Issue: when I am using `Thread.Sleep`, code is working fine but when I am using explicit wait & implicit wait it's not working.
I have added Implicit in my base class at the time of driver initialization.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
public class nextGenAutomationLoginPage extends Base {

    @FindBy(xpath = "(//button[@class='_1YW_5'])[1]")
    WebElement login;

    public nextGenAutomationLoginPage() {
        super();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void clickOnLogin() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        // Thread.sleep(2000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(login));
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(login, By.xpath("//div[@class='_10b1I']") ));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", login);
        login.click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@class='_1YW_5'])[1]")).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='comp-kaoxkn4a1']")));
        String sign = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='comp-kaoxkn4a1']/h1/span")).getText();
        System.out.println(sign);
    }
```

Note: I tried to add Scroll as well to add some wait before clicking.

DOM:
[image]
Please let me know if i am missing anything here.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got the point whats happening here :

1. Manually navigate to URL: [https://www.nextgenerationautomation.com](https://Navigate%20to%20URL:%20https://www.nextgenerationautomation.com)  (Selenium also loading this URL)
2. Manually Immediately keep clicking on "LogIn/SignUp button" (Selenium also able to click therefore NO error in console )
3. "LogIn/SignUp" page not opening unless [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg66y.png) (LinkedIn following count widget ) gets appear on screen
4. Once [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MslB.png) gets appear manually click on "LogIn/SignUp button", now Login page is opening (Selenium able to click after Thread.Sleep)

Summery:

1. This is a codding defect on that page.
2. "LogIn/SignUp" is not clickable until  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7GNJ.png)  gets added on page
3. Your selenium code is perfectly fine :)
4. Xpath I have used is `//span[text()='Log In / SignUp']`

Thanks KS

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as *`Log In / SignUp`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'defaultAvatar')]//following::span[text()='Log In / SignUp']")).click();
  ```

However, as the element is a dynamic element, so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'defaultAvatar')]//following::span[text()='Log In / SignUp']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I tried this code but still not working  ``` public class nextGenAutomationLoginPage extends Base {  

 @FindBy(xpath = "//span[text()='Log In / SignUp']")
 WebElement login;
public void clickOnLogin() throws InterruptedException {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Log In / SignUp']"))).click();

Comment: When i am using Thread.Sleep , its working. Can you please help me to get rid of Thread.Sleep somwhow

Comment: What error do you see exactly?

Comment: No error its just not clicking on Login .. so the assertions for next page is failing

Comment: Can you try the updated xpath and let me know the status please?

Comment: Its still not working.... However the updtated xpath worked with Thread.Sleep

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is clicking the login button before the page is loaded properly. please add visibility condition.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
```

Comment: Tried , its not working and surprisingly its not throwing any error ..:-(

Comment: Your code is clicking the element properly. That is why, no error.i ll try the same and let you know

Comment: I am seeing this console error, it is clicking the button properly.
The resource <url> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.